# Tryind to display json object into blade php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to display this json column into blade file

But i get Trying to get proprty 'en' of non object

````
    <tr>
        <th>Title en</th>
        <th>Title ar</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Session Number</th>
        <th>Session Per Week</th>
        <th>Session Duration</th>
        <th>Show</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($model as $program)

        <tr>
            <th>{{json_decode($program->title)->en}}</th>
            <th>{{json_decode($program->title)->ar}}</th>
            <th>{{$program->description}}</th>
            <th>{{$program->sessions_number}}</th>
            <th>{{$program->sessions_per_week}}</th>
            <th>{{$program->session_duration}}</th>
            <th>{{$program->is_shown ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</th>

        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </thead>```
````

Comment: Try doing a `dd($program->title);` and see what you get back, it's likely not what you are expecting if you're receiving this error.

Comment: The error is saying that the result of `json_decode($program->title)` is not an object.

Comment: You **shouldn't** decode json in the blade template in the first place. least it should be done repeatedly

Comment: when i `dd($program->title);` i got the title en

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense to you and now you know how to access your value(s) correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it appeared that my column was in trasnlatable array
and i just needed to call getTranslation mehtod and path to it the col and the app local jsu like that
`{{getTranslation('title', 'en')}}`

Answer (score 1):

if your JSON format is something like

`{"en":"title", "ar":"other-title"}`

Then it should work.

My best guess is the `en` key doesn't exist on that title property.

If you are using the latest PHP then you can use the Nullsafe operator (?->) if not then use the `isset` check or use the null coalescing operator `??`

```
 <th>{{json_decode($program->title)->en ?? '' }}</th>
```

Also, be sure that `$program->title` itself is not null doing something like:

```
@php $title = isset($program->title) ? json_decode($program->title): null @endphp 
   <th>{{$title->en ?? '' }}</th>
```

But it is better to create a [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for this type of thing in the eloquent model. So you can directly do something like

```
$program->en_title;
```

So the blade file is clean and easy to understand but I don't suggest to go Accessor path if you are not reusing the code even if it makes the code cleaner. It is just my preference.

Comment: `en` and `ar` are exists in the title property and i'm using php 7.4

and if i used coalescing operator it return the two fields with null  `??` 

but when i dd $program->title i got the title on en

Comment: I couldn't understand how your JSON data is being set it is better you post the output you are getting of `dd` in the OP section too. Also, are you using `??` operator on both `en` and `ar`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your title property is not an object, you should debug first to check it out, use `dd()` function to see inside this property